# terminate excuation of block in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
- (void)beat{
    __block UInt64 total_frames = 0; 
    // The next frame that the beat will play on
    static UInt64 next_beat_frame = 0;
    static UInt64 next_tick_frame = 0;
    static BOOL making_beat = NO;
    static BOOL tick=NO;
    _bpm=self.tempo_slider.value;
    // Oscillator specifics - instead you can easily load the samples from cowbell.aif or somesuch
    float oscillatorRate = 440./44100.0;
    __block float oscillatorPosition = 0; // this is outside the block since beats can span calls to the block
    self.blockChannel.volume=0.5;
        // The block that is our metronome
    self.blockChannel = [AEBlockChannel channelWithBlock:^(const AudioTimeStamp *time, UInt32 frames, AudioBufferList *audio) {
        UInt64 frames_between_beats = 44100/(_bpm/60.);
        UInt64 end_frame=frames_between_beats*_midi_length;
        // For each frame, count and if we reach the frame that should start a beat, start the beat
// frames=_length;
        for (int i=0; i<frames; i++) { // frame...by frame...
            if(end_frame==total_frames){
                if (_recordStatus != 0){

                    total_frames=0;
                    next_beat_frame =0;
                    next_tick_frame=0;
                    oscillatorPosition = 0;
                    _recordStatus=0;
                }
                NSLog(@"forever here");
                return;
            }            
            if (next_beat_frame == total_frames) { 
                making_beat = YES;
                oscillatorPosition = 0; // reset the osc position to make them all sound the same
                next_tick_frame=next_beat_frame+frames_between_beats;
                next_beat_frame += _upper_timesig*frames_between_beats;

            }
              total_frames++;
        }
    }];
    // Add the block channel to the audio controller
    [_audioController addChannels:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_blockChannel]];   
}
```

The logic of above code is running the block and total_frames will increment. When it reaches end_frame, it will terminate the block and reset everything. When it reaches next_beats, it will beats.

Currently I am trying to use return to terminate the block. In fact, it works. But when I re-execute the block, it wont reach the return statement, instead it will execute

```
total_frames=0;
next_beat_frame =0;
next_tick_frame=0;
oscillatorPosition = 0;
 _recordStatus=0; .
```

then continue run the block, when it reaches above code again, nothing 
 It , and execute the lane before return statement  NSLog(@"forever here"); forever. Why return does not work second time?If I go to the previous view and go back to this view, the block will run ok.

Second question, if I am changing the view, and I wanna terminate the block. What should I do in the block or generally in objective c, how can I detect the view changes.

Third question, what is exactly difference between static and __block variable in the block?

Comment: `static` variables keep their value. They are only initialized once in the lifetime of the app process.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy,if I changed those static variables in the block, this value is not changed outside block right? If I rerun this method, will next_beat_frame declared as static remain 0 all the time? Does return statement terminate the block?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by resetting variables instead of terminating the block. I will let block run in the background. Whenever I want to use it, I will reset 
                    total_frames=0;
                    next_beat_frame =0;
                    next_tick_frame=0;
                    oscillatorPosition

So, I change variables to __block.